# Minecraft for Switch: P2 Controls and Profile not getting saved

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I play Minecraft on the Nintendo Switch in 2-player mode and customize the controls or profile (character appearance), and then save and leave... I come back and none of that customization has been saved!

How do I get Minecraft to actually save and remember my settings?